# Documentation - Version is not valid in this context

Tags: bug, documentation, documentation-editor

This is what I am trying to Edit - https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/python/809/compatibility-between-python-3-and-python-2#

Look for `True False or None`

I noticed the versions are just mentioned but are not added as a markup so I tried doing the same however but it's popping up error `Version is not valid in this context`. Not sure What is causing that.

Sample Code which I formatted:

```
<!-- if version <Python 2.x> [gte > 2.0] -->
    True, False = False, True
    True   # False
    False  # True
<!-- end version if -->

You can't do this with `None` since Python 2.4.

<!-- if version <Python 2.x> [gte 2.4] -->
    None = None  # SyntaxError: cannot assign to None
<!-- end version if -->
```

Comment: `gte > 2.0`? Maybe remove the `>’?

Comment: yes that was the issue, thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem seems to be this line:

```
<!-- if version <Python 2.x> [gte > 2.0] -->
```

The problem is the `>` in `[gte > 2.0]`. To fix, replace with this line:

```
<!-- if version <Python 2.x> [gte 2.0] -->
```